# excel vba last column for updating validation list

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble with getting a data validation list to adjust based on the last column from content in row `5`.

Here is what i have currently.

```
Sub DataRange_F() 'Foundation Drop Down List
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim LastCol As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WholeRng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsR As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Add New")
Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foundation Plates")

wsR.Activate
Set Rng = Cells

    LastCol = Rng.Find(What:="*", After:=Rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

    Set WholeRng = Range(Cells(5, "C"), Cells(5, LastCol))

    ws.Activate
    With ws.Range("E8").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=WholeRng
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
    End With

Set ws = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It keeps stopping at the `Formula1:=` part. This is where i am stuck. How can i add my range in that Formula? Or is there another way?

> Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `Formula1:="=" & WholeRng.Address` ?

Comment: Doesn't `Operator:=xlBetween` require both a `Formula1` and a `Formula2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i got to work.

```
Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
    GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function

Sub DataRange()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim startCol As String
Dim startRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim myCol As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foundation Plates")
Dim sht7 As Worksheet
Set sht7 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Legend")

Call Unprotect
sht2.Activate

startCol = "C"
startRow = 5
lastCol = sht2.Cells(5, sht2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
myCol = GetColumnLetter(lastCol)

Set rng = sht2.Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & "5")

'For error checking the range
'MsgBox rng.Address

    sht7.Activate
    With sht7.Range("F8").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & "'" & sht2.Name & "'!" & rng.Address
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
    End With

Call Protect
sht2.Activate

Set sht2 = Nothing
Set sht7 = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this...

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & "'" & wsR.Name & "'!" & WholeRng.Address
```

Comment: Thx, This does something. It adds a few columns to the data list but not all. So now im debugging my `WholeRng`. Its not selecting the range until the end. By chance do you see anything that i messed up?

Comment: Try using LastCol = wsR.UsedRange.Columns.Count Also check the in data validation, what range is used as a source?

Answer (score 1):

Try it as,

```
..., Formula1:=Chr(61) & WholeRng.Cells(1).Address(external:=true), Formula2:=Chr(61) & WholeRng.Cells(WholeRng.Cells.Count).Address(external:=true)
```